# How to add textwatcher to material datepicker dialog's text field input in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datepicker, material-components-android

I am trying to add a slash(/) when user type date in this format DD/MM/YYYY, I need to add slash automatically once user type DD and MM, I am thing of using text watcher here but how can I access DatePicker text input field?

I still haven't tried anything yet, I am really confused, how to access that Text input field of material DatePicker dialog

Comment: "*I still haven't tried anything yet*", so go ahead and try it! If you have any questions afer trying, you can explain them more clearly and with a focus.